# Catch a specific `Windows Error` number - python

Tags: python, windows, exception

I am creating a new nested directory (`data_dir = 'parent\child'`) in python:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(data_dir)
except WindowsError:
    pass
```

If the parent directory `'parent'` did not exists (yet, 'cause I might be setting later in the code), then the code caught that as a `Windows Error 3` and moved on.

However now what could also happen is `Windows Error 206` which is when the filename or extension is too long. For which I would need to take a separate action.

---

Is there a way to distinguish between `Windows Error` `3` and `206` (and others) so as to raise distinct `Exceptions`?

Comment: In this case, if long paths aren't enabled (Windows 10 + Python 3.6+), then a path that's too long will also result in `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3) if it exceeds `MAX_PATH`, which is 260 characters, including the terminating NUL (e.g. `os.mkdir('C:/Temp/' + 'a' * 252)`. You'll see `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE` (206) instead if the resulting path doesn't leave space for at least an 8.3 short filename (e.g. `os.mkdir('C:/Temp/' + 'a' * 240)`).

Comment: If the directory name itself exceeds the file system limit (e.g. 255 characters), the error is typically `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` (123).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use *WindowsError.winerror* (inherited from *OSError*: [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Exceptions - winerror](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError.winerror)) to differentiate between underlying errors. Something like:

> ```py
> >>> def create_dir(path):
> ...     try:
> ...         os.mkdir(path)
> ...     except WindowsError as e:
> ...         if e.winerror == 3:
> ...             print("Handling WindowsError 3")
> ...         elif e.winerror == 206:
> ...             print("Handling WindowsError 206")
> ...         else:
> ...             print("Handling other WindowsError")
> ...     except:
> ...         print("Handling other exceptions")
> ...
> >>>
> >>> create_dir("not/existing")
> Handling WindowsError 3
> >>> create_dir("a" * 228)
> Handling WindowsError 206
> >>> create_dir(":")
> Handling other WindowsError
> ```

Of course, *WindowsError **3*** can easily be avoided, using [[Python.Docs]: os.makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

Comment: When you're looking to handle specific error codes, the default for all other error codes should be a `raise` statement.

Comment: @eryksun: I know, *OP* also mentioned this fact (for all cases). But I was only trying to prove the concept, and if I was to raise exceptions, their tracebacks would generate to much output.

Comment: Handling other cases is an obvious extrapolation of the first two cases, but knowing to include a bare `raise` statement for unhandled error codes isn't obvious.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [CristiFati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541181/catch-a-specific-windows-error-number-python/52541414#52541414)-s solution, a better way to **avoid magic numbers**, would be using the winerror of the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) module:

```
     import winerror
     try:
         os.mkdir(path)
     except WindowsError as e:
         if e.winerror == winerror.ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
             print("Handling WindowsError 3")
         elif e.winerror == winerror.ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE:
             print("Handling WindowsError 206")
         else:
             print("Handling other WindowsError")
     except:
         print("Handling other exceptions")
```